# In Hive, what does the 'positive' function do?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm working on an item-based recommender using data stored in Hive tables and stumbled across a similar scenario in [Sagar Prasad's blog](http://sagarprasad.blogspot.com/2014/08/simple-item-based-recommendation-using.html). I notice that he uses the `POSITIVE` function on the hashes of the user/product.

I'm a bit confused as to why this function exists. The [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) states that this function takes an `int` or `double` and returns that value:

> "positive(INT/DOUBLE a) returns a"

For example:

```
hive> select positive(-1);
-1
```

Does that mean that the function doesn't do anything? Or am I missing some subtle nuance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood this function is `GenericUDFOPPositive.java` which extends `GenericUDFBaseUnary.java`. `positive` can also be called simply as `+`.

For numeric types, this function does indeed do effectively nothing. For text types, it appears to attempt to do a conversion to `double`, since `GenericUDFBaseUnary.java` contains the following:

```
private PrimitiveTypeInfo deriveResultTypeInfo(PrimitiveTypeInfo typeInfo) {
  switch(typeInfo.getPrimitiveCategory()) {
    case STRING:
    case VARCHAR:
    case CHAR:
      return TypeInfoFactory.doubleTypeInfo;
    default:
      return typeInfo;
  }
}
```

However this doesn't seem to actually work, as calling `positive` on a string simply returns the string. This implies that at the least, the type signature of this function in the documentation is wrong, as it accepts more than just `double` and `int`.

Don't worry about being confused, having read the source code to try and work out what this function is for, I'm also now confused about why it exists!

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/release-0.14.0/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFOPPositive.java

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/release-0.14.0/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFBaseUnary.java